# CORS header error when i use ajax request from my front end to access db in Tomcat , maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

So i created this resource which returns an array of products.

```
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object getbook()
    {
        Products p = new Products();
        
        
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        return gson.toJson(p.getAll());
    }
```

But when i call this api from my front end it says
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8085/demoRest/webapi/myresource' from origin 'http://localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

here is my ajax request

```
$(function() {
var val = "";
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        url:  "http://localhost:8085/demoRest/webapi/myresource",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("response:" + data);
            //$.each(data, function(j, pdata) {
              //  val= val + "[ "+pdata.title +" " + pdata.author +"]";
           // });
           // $("#data").text(val);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(' Error in processing! '+textStatus);
        }
    });
});
});
```

My Webxml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.demoRest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Using tomcat version 10

Answer (score -1):

So i guess you should learn about CORS policy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

The user will block the request if you uses XMLHttpRequest from
Host A to Host B without permission of Host B.

However, we can by pass CORS by adding few headers at Host B. The backend api often use this policy to handle many different requests which come from different host.

You can take an example here:

```
((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");
```

More detail:

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/